# Jquery Addition Operation

Tags: jquery, addition

Hi i wrote a jquery script. I'm rookie on jquery. i want to increase cart count +1. But this script didn't add +1 it concats 1. What should i do ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $('#shopping-cart-button').click(function(){
          var cart_count = $('#cart_count').text();
          cart_count = cart_count + 1;
          $('#cart_count').text(cart_count);
          });
</script>
```

Comment: what is `#basket_count`?

Comment: use parseInt.,.. [parseInt](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`.text()` returns string, so you have to use **[`parseInt(value, radix)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)** to convert the string to number.

```
$('#shopping-cart-button').click(function(){
    var basket_count = $('#basket_count').text();
    basket_count = parseInt(basket_count, 10) + 1;
    $('#basket_count').text(basket_count);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try for something like this in case of input type text

```
$('YOUR_ID_HERE').val($('YOUR_ID_HERE').val() + 'SOME OTHER VALUE');
```